# How to mount a zfs filesystem on another zfs filesystem in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

With ubuntu 14.04 I had two zfs mount points set to legacy so I could mount one filesystem on another via fstab. I.e:

```
zfs_1/base /home/xyz

zfs_2/photo /home/xyz/stuff/photo
```

With ubuntu 16.04 zfs is not loaded before fstab is processed so I tried to remove the legacy mount points and set the mount points on the file systems.

The problem is I don't see how to set a mount order. If `zfs_2/photo` is mounted first it will auto-create the tree and then `zfs_1/base` will fail to mount since the directory is not empty. Is there a simple fix for this issue with 16.04 ?

I had a related issue that I would bind photo to an exported nfs volume `/export/photo`; but I think I can solve that problem via using a symlink `/export/photo -> /home/xyz/stuff/photo` and then still export `/export/photo` via nfs (need to test it).

The easiest solution would be to revert to legacy and use `/etc/fstab` but from what I have read in ubuntu forum this does not seem to be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force ZFS to be loaded early by including it into a file in `/etc/modules-load.d/*.conf`.  Say, we create `/etc/modules-load.d/zfs.conf` with the following content:

```
zfs
```

The code itself also comes with a `systemd` service (actually a [couple of them](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/tree/master/etc/systemd/system)) and you can add system dependencies with the latest mount implementations.  For example:

```
/zfs_1/base  /home/xyz               none  defaults,bind,x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.service  0  0

/zfs_2/photo  /home/xyz/stuff/photo  none  defaults,bind,x-systemd.requires=zfs-mount.service  0  0
```

(Disclaimer: I am aware that `x-systemd.requires` works on the latest Arch and Debian Testing, may not be there yet in Ubuntu 16.04, although it is in the [mount man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man5/systemd.mount.5.html))

Comment: The 'bind' was not correct but the x-systemd.requires=zfs... was sufficient to make it work; /etc/modules did not have to be edited. Thanks!